# Firebase Cloud Messaging Error in Android app

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to integrate FCM in my android app to enable it to receive push notifications from server. As reference, I followed all the steps in this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client to configure my client android app.

**PROBLEM ENCOUNTERED:**
When I try to send a notification to my android app using Firebase notification console, nothing is happening as it doesn't trigger the **onMessageReceived**. If I try to use Postman to send a notification, I get **status code 200 OK** as response, but nothing is happening on client side.

Here is my code:

**MessagingService.java**

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public static String TAG = MessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.e(TAG,"NEW TOKEN IS: "+s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.e(TAG,"NEW MESSAGE RECEIVED FROM SERVER!");
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application>
.....

<activity>
......
</activity>

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="fcm_default_channel" />

<service android:name="ats.it.vn.furgodemo.util.notification.MessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

</application>
```

Can someone help me please?
Thanks in advance